# Can Reliable Collections be used outside of Service Fabric?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have an existing application that would greatly benefit from reliable collections, but I don't want to port all or part of it to Service Fabric. Is it possible to make use of the Reliable Collections with a custom backend that isn't part of Service Fabric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are part of Service Fabric stateful programming model, however you can use collections from System.Collections.Concurrent and save the state in Redis Cache for example.

Comment: I figured that is the case, just wanted to see if anyone knows differently.